# Reactjs fetchJsonp call raise timeout error

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, jsonp

I have a webservice that return a JSON string using application/json as the content type. Using Reactjs fetchJsonp function its got "**timeout Error**". This is my code block

```
  fetchJsonp("http://192.168.0.77/test/json.php", {
  method: 'GET'
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson;
   })
  .catch((error) => {
       //return error;
       console.error(error);
  });
```

When i run this code i got error like 
**index.js:2177 Error: JSONP request to http://192.168.0.77/test/json.php timed out**

Comment: Most probably an issue with your end point.  Check whether the service is up

Comment: I just inspect the network window its showing this call and its response